# How to get vehicle number using Google maps api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a latitude and longitude of two places. I can get the direction to reach the destination by below api with mode=transit and transit_mode=train.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?&mode=transit&origin=dombivli&destination=titvala&alternatives=true&transit_mode=train&key=yourAPIkey

But it does not return Train no. [image: as it is shown in Google map]

Can we get the train number between the specified location using any API

Comment: I believe it might be a valid feature request for Directions API web service. Just file it in the public [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com).

Comment: @xomena yaa I have already did that now just waiting for their response